# I want to compare e remove duplicates of copied values in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, excel-2019

I have a question about the macro that I am running. I want to copy / paste the values cross sheet, but the target sheet I want to compare the values and remove duplicates of intercalated columns.
So, the copy and paste is working well, but to comparing and removing duplicates is not working.

Is there something else that I should try in my Macro?

```
Sub GetInformation()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'some comments
   
    Sheets("SpExtra").Select
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CRToday").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("5lbExt").Select
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CRInformationToday").Select
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("20LBExtra").Select
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CRToday").Select
    Range("G1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Sheets("JRExtra").Select
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CRToday").Select
    Range("J1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("SExtra").Select
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CRToday").Select
    Range("M1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    

    'some comments 
    Sheets("CRToday").Select
    Range("J2:J4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CRSts").Select
    Range("J3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
   
        
    Sheets("CRToday").Select
    Range("A2:A12").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CRSts").Select
    Range("N3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
           
    Sheets("CRToday").Select
    Range("M2:M4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CRSts").Select
    Range("R3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
           
    Sheets("CRToday").Select
    Range("D2:D14").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CRSts").Select
    Range("V3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
           
    Sheets("CRToday").Select
    Range("D15:D27").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CRSts").Select
    Range("V17").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
          
    Sheets("CRToday").Select
    Range("G2:G10").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CRSts").Select
    Range("Z3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(10, 14, 18, 22, 26), Header _
        :=xlYes
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Specify the range instead of `usedrange`? Also set ranges to each other if you are pasting values.

Comment: Do you mind to share an example?

Comment: You used tons of ranges in your code. To set ranges to each other just do range().value=range().value